# Is it possible to use email name other than "DoNotReply" in Azure Email Communication Services?

Tags: azure, email, azure-communication-services

I have configured email notifications using the [Azure Communication Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/create-email-communication-resource). However, the emails are always sent from the "**DoNotReply**" user. Would it be possible to use something more meaningful for the users to understand/fitler the emails?

[image]

---

The portal only shows a single option, even with a custom domain:

[image]

I have tried changing "replyTo" (although no reply is obviously intended), but that did not help, outlook/gmail still showed the "DoNoReply" as sender. Can I somehow change the sender so that it looks nicer for the users?

The code I have tried with "replyTo" is below:

```
const client = new EmailClient(connectionString);

const emailMessage: EmailMessage = {
  senderAddress: "DoNotReply@xxxx-2b75-4a91-a222-d4d55c7c8b20.azurecomm.net",
  replyTo: [
    {
      address: "SomeFancyEmail@somewhere.net",
      displayName: "Some Fancy Name"
    }
  ],
  content: {
    subject,
    html
  },
  recipients
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly possible to do so. Please see the detailed instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/add-multiple-senders.

Currently you can do so by following these steps in Azure portal:

1. Go to your Email Communication Service.
2. Click on "Domains" (left side menu) and then click on your domain.
3. Click on "Provision Domains" (left side menu) and then click on the domain again.
4. Click on "Mail From Address" (left side menu) and then click on "Add" button to add the desired email address.

You should also be able to do so by using one of the available SDKs for communication service.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, a mere link to an off-site solution is not an acceptable answer here; at the very least, please summarize what’s behind the link, in case it stops working, or visitors are unable or unwilling to click through.

Comment: @tripleee - Thanks for delayed welcome :). Good point though. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Add/Update/Delete is disabled for me